# Java binary literal usage

Tags: java, binary

All examples on binary literal is like:
`int a=0b1011`
My question is, can I translate existing variables to this form? For example,
from`int b=10000011;` I want to get `int c=0b10000011`.

Comment: How would you do the translation? Decimal 10000011 is different from binary 10000011, which is 131 in decimal?

Comment: I don't need them to be equal...This is just an example, saying what I'm looking for.Like for `String`, we can write `String c = "0b"+"10000011"`, I'm just curious about how to add binary literal to any existing `int`.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking for here. Why would you want to change `int b = 10000011` to `int c=0b10000011`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Integer.parseInt(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-) and something like,

```
int b = 10000011;
int c = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(b), 2);
int d = 0b10000011;
System.out.println(c == d);
```

And I get `true`.

Comment: The problem is that c is implicitly an integer in binary form.  `System.out.println(c)` just show its integer value.

Comment: Binary computers store everything in binary. It represents the decimal literal in decimal. Please clarify what problem you're trying to solve. If you want the binary value of `c` call `Integer.toBinaryString(c)`

Comment: Then it will return a `String` not `int`. Anyway, I think this is the only choice, though it has to translate `int` to `String`, and `String` to `int`.